# how to create update slick multiple row?

Tags: scala, playframework, slick

i have this code !!
this code for insert multiple row..

```
def insertDocSetting(data: List[ModelDocumentSetting]) = DocumentSettingTable ++= data
```

and this is for update multiple row!!

```
    def updateDocSetting(data: Seq[ModelDocumentSetting])= { 
         for (a <- data){    
         DocumentSettingTable.filter(_.doc_proc_list_id === a.doc_proc_list_id).update(a)
        }  
    }
```

but ,i have problem to get the result..
how to create slick update multiple row

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to map the result of your filter into a tuple before you can update it.
You can check how to do it [in the documentation](http://slick.lightbend.com/doc/3.1.1/sql-to-slick.html#update). But it will be something like:

```
def updateDocSetting(data: Seq[ModelDocumentSetting])= { 
   for (a <- data){    
     DocumentSettingTable
       .filter(_.doc_proc_list_id === a.doc_proc_list_id)
       .map(doc => (doc.element1, doc.element2))
       .update(("new element1", "new element2"))
   }  
 }
```